# iOS compile library/framework linker flags issues compiling for device but not simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build, cocoapods

### Background:

I'm trying to use a Phonegap with cocoapods. Phonegap already has issues compiling from command line so I'm just using Xcode with the generated project file (and assumably I'd have to do that anyway when using cocoapods).

I've pushed up on Github a reproduced empty project with my problem:
https://github.com/Dan2552/phonegap-reproducable-issue

You can see the steps I made after making a plain brand-new Phonegap app in the `build_ios` script in the root directory on the repo. But I've also pushed up the generated project files (platforms/ios) so anybody without Phonegap should be able to open the project.

### Problem:

I'm having a weird issue with compiling. Probably issues with the pre-bundled Cordova library and cocoapods.

When building without doing anything after generating the project with Phonegap and adding in the cocoapods, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTPublisher", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libPods.a(OpenTokPlugin.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libPods.a(OpenTokPlugin.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSubscriber", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libPods.a(OpenTokPlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Cocoapods warns:

> [!] The target `HelloWorld [Debug]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
>
> [!] The target `HelloWorld [Debug - Release]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.

and therefore I tried deleting the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` ('Other Linker Flags' in Xcode) entry altogether. **This successfully compiles on an iOS device**, but not on the simulator, nor will the project build on archive.

Building for simulator will get the same error as before (`Undefined symbols for architecture`)

Building for archive will get
`/Users/dan2552/projects/ReproducableProblems/OpenTokPhonegap/Classes/OpentokPlugin.h:9:9: 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found`

I've also tried putting `$(inherited)` in the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` which produces the same results as deleting them.

Comment: Wondering why you are getting i.386 errors for an ARM build ? Could it be you are trying to link against Intel i.386 libaries instead of ARM ? Something to so with the Android Intel Atom support or Android simulator ? Not sure as I haven't used PhoneGap in anger.

Comment: Android shouldn't affect it in anyway, if you look in the platforms/ios directory you can see that you get a normal(ish) Xcode project but I agree that it's weird - maybe it compiles i386 for the simulator (as it's not an emulator)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your included framework has no Simulator (i386) slice:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info Pods/OpenTokSDK-WebRTC/Opentok.framework/Versions/A/Opentok 
Architectures in the fat file: Pods/OpenTokSDK-WebRTC/Opentok.framework/Versions/A/Opentok are: armv7 armv7s
```

So its classes can't be linked for the Simulator.

---

Also if you plan to use CocoaPods you could remove the Cordova project and static library entirely and add `pod 'Cordova'` to your Podfile.

Comment: We've since ditched Phonegap/Cordova. It's true, OpenTok won't compile for the simulator. We resolved the compile issues by using `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` around the OpenTok specific class.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues before when trying to run the Xcode project, rather than the XCWorkspace. The issue you're having sounds like it's because you're not running the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your taget Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited) to a new line .
. Try this